How to delete cookies in Rails 7.1?
I recently upgraded my Rails app from version 7.0.4.3 to version 7.1.3.4 and cookies.delete stopped working.
I'm setting a cookie in JavaScript with:
document.cookie = `last_guess=value; path=/`;

then process and remove the cookie with an action (before_action) inside ApplicationController with:
cookie_value = cookies.delete(:last_guess)

This is working fine with version 7.0.4.3. However it stopped working with version 7.1.3.4.
If I print out the cookies after delete, the cookie is part of @delete_cookies:
#<ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar:0x000000011432d0b0 @set_cookies={}, @delete_cookies={"last_guess"=>{:domain=>"localhost", :path=>"/", :same_site=>:lax}},...

but the cookie is still present in the browser. I tried deleting the cookie with options like domain: "localhost", path: "/", same_site: :lax, but it didn't help.
Am I missing something for this to work correctly?

You don't actually delete cookies from the browser. What you do is send a new Set-Cookie header with an expiry in the past which causes the browser to discard the cookie. Anyways that's what rails should be doing - but check the web inspector in the browser to see what headers are present in the response.

It is returning the set-cookie header as an array, that's probably where the issues is. Copying the value from the browser:
["_com_session=xxx; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax", "last_guess=; path=/; max-age=0; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; samesite=lax"]

Hmm, looks like some sort of serialization error when converting the cookie jar into headers.

Maybe try and see if you can reproduce the issue using the Rails bug report template? https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/guides/bug_report_templates/action_controller.rb

it must be something with my application and the way I upgraded it. If I create a new rails app from scratch, with version 7.1.3.4, then this is not happening. Will have to figure out what the difference is. Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.cookies_serializer is :json in both versions
